# Can't show custom text in block over product description

Tags: module, magento-1, blocks

I have added this xml in `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/mymodule.xml`

```
<layout version="1.0.1">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="mymodule/showicon" after="product.info.media" name="mymodule_showicon" template="mymodule/showicon.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

for testing I have shown following code in `showicon.phtml` afterwards I will show a image **that I want to overlay the products image**

```
<h1>SHOW ICON HERE</h1>
```

and in my confix.xml I have defined

```
    <config>
    <modules>
        <NS_Mymodule>
            <version>1.0.1</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </NS_Mymodule>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Mymodule>
                <class>NS_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </Mymodule>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>NS_Mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

Now as expected I don't see the text **SHOW ICON HERE** in my product page,

whats wrong, whats I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

I've also added the block class with the code

```
class Ns_Mymodule_Block_Showicon extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {
        return "Hello tuts+ world";
    }
}
```

I have also called the block in the view.phtml file at rwd/default/template/catalog/product

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymodule_showicon') ?>
```

after this line

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
```

Comment: Update your module config.xml here

Comment: @PankajPareek please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout xml as below:

```
<layout version="1.0.1">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="mymodule/showicon" after="product.info.media" name="mymodule_showicon" template="mymodule/showicon.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

You need to add content reference as well. If you want to use above layout xml then you have to call the block in `view.phtml`

**Update**

Module Configuration (app\etc\modules\NS_Mymodule.xml)

```
<config>
<modules>
    <NS_Mymodule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </NS_Mymodule>
</modules>
</config>
```

Configuration XML (app\code\community\NS\Mymodule\etc\config.xml)

```
<config>
<modules>
    <NS_Mymodule>
        <version>1.0.1</version> 
    </NS_Mymodule>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <Mymodule>
            <class>NS_Mymodule_Helper</class>
        </Mymodule>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <mymodule>
            <class>NS_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mymodule>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mymodule>
                <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Block Class ( app\code\community\NS\Mymodule\Block\Showicon.php )

```
class Ns_Mymodule_Block_Showicon extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public function myfunction()
{
    return "Hello tuts+ world";
}
}
```

Layout XML ( app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\mymodule.xml)

```
<layout version="1.0.1">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <reference name="product.info.extrahint">
                <block type="mymodule/showicon" after="product.info.media" name="mymodule_showicon" template="mymodule/showicon.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Template File (app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\mymodule\showicon.phtml)

Test Module

Comment: no, It doesn't work

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: still the same result,

Comment: I created the module its working fine at my end.

Comment: I have called the block in view.phtml like this `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymodule_showicon') ?>`

Comment: try this one <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymodule_showicon', true, true) ?>

Comment: @Arunendra `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>` this shows the product data twice, but still not the required text,

Comment: can you share the plugin you just created with my example?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: ok thanks, I'm looking in it, also what version of magento you try it in? mine is magento 1.9

Comment: `1.9.2.1` to be more specific ..

Comment: thanks, that works, also can you tell me how I can put this in `product.info.media` rather of `product.info.extrahint` when I change it in the above code the it stops working,